# How can I tell that the Foundry Action I triggered via API finished?

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

API queries are made from a third party app to trigger Actions to update data. Subsequent queries and actions need to wait until the edits have been made to the Ontology. Is there a way to track when this is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Object Storage V2 you have read after write guarantees, and don't need to worry about this.

If you are using Object Storage V1 then that's backed by elastic search, and you'll have eventual consistency once the Foundry Action write finishes propagating through the ES shards.